# list box items context menu WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

I have list box that contains UserControl as item template

the user control contains few text blocks in a grid, 
the thing  is that I want to add context menu to my user control that will show on the list item right click but currently only right clicking the  textbox inside the user control triggers the context menu appearance

clicking the spaces between those textboxes triggers nothing,

any idea about how can I trigger the context menu from the container list box?

Thanks

Eran

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it you have set the context menu at the textbox level of the usercontrol.

If you want the context menu to function for the entire user control you would need to set teh contextmenu of the user control at the item template level.

Comment: Thanks for replying,
I defind it as <UserControl.ContextNenu> I guess that the level user control unless I'm wrong